Alternative to Azure Personalizer AI service
Azure Personalizer will be retired on 1st October 2026.
We use this service on our website to power a "Recommended articles" section.
The Rank & Rewards APIs are used to train the ML model.
Now that it will be no longer in use, what would be the best Microsoft AI service alternative?
We need an AI service that can produce recommendation via reinforcement learning through user feedback.


Now that it will be no longer in use, what would be the best Microsoft AI service alternative?

There was an alternative approach create custom reinforcement learning models using Azure Machine Learning. Check this doc for reference. This will involve building and training models from scratch using pre-built models and frameworks.

It Provides a drag-and-drop interface for building models, including those for reinforcement learning.

After training is completed in Azure ML, See the below agent that how well it performs. It is seen successfully navigating the maze Training this agent takes around 90 minutes using the configuration in the Minecraft code sample.



You can also leverage Spark MLlib or other libraries for reinforcement learning. Use Spark-based pools in Azure Synapse Analytics to implement custom recommendation systems.
Reference:

Azure Machine Learning - Reinforcement Learning (Public Preview)

Configure and submit training jobs


